# How to calculate hysteresis when the OPAMP supply voltage is changing

Tags: operational-amplifier, comparator, hysteresis

I have designed a GSM/GPS based tracker which is installed at my bike. But it is draining battery too quickly.

So, I want to add a cutoff circuit when the bike is not running(battery not charging) for a long time and in addition, the cutoff circuit should reconnect power to load (my tracker) whenever the battery voltage rises to a preset leve (For say 12.6v).

I decided to use an op amp comparator based cutoff circuit. But the problem is I am unable to calculate hysteresis when the supply voltage of the op amp is changing (Because I will power the op amp from the battery itself).

Can I use a comparator hysteresis circuit if I have a variable voltage rail? If not what kind of changes to the circuit would I need to make this functional?
[image]

Comment: You may want to crop that image and re-post it, posts are forever and we want them to look good for future reference.

Answer (score -1):

If you want LOW POWER, at limited Temperature Excursion, try this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSaKeS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

By the way, this schem is edited (added output Zener/diode clamp) to provide more stable Vhysteresis.

Comment: How to calculate the value of R5 when the supply voltage of te op-amp itself is changing??That is my concern!!

Comment: I am attaching a circuit that i designed so far..

Comment: @S.Das downvote answers that don't answer the question

Comment: @s.das  You did not ask for constant hysteresis. Nor does the circuit you attached accomplish constant hysteresis.

Comment: Consider added an output clamp, to achieve more stable hysteresis.